# How to capture the Facebook like count from an official Facebook button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have tried this code and it keeps returning undefined:

```
setTimeout("alert($('div.connect_widget_button_count_count').val());", 10000);
```

I wait 10 seconds to allow for the bloated facebook button and counter to load.

I then issue an alert with the value of the **div** with **class='connect_widget_button_count_count'** which usually looks like this when loaded to the web page:

```
<div class='connect_widget_button_count_count'>4</div>
```

With 4 being the official facebook "count" number.

**How can I capture the Facebook like/share/count number as a javascript variable from the official Facebook button?**

According to firebug, this is what the surrounding HTML looks like:

```
<table class="connect_widget_interactive_area">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="connect_widget_button_count_excluding">
            <table class="uiGrid" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <div class="connect_widget_button_count_count">2</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facebook plugins are rendered inside an iframe, the domain of that iframe differs from the domain of your page (since you don't host it on facebook.com) and because of that you have no access to that document.

Browsers block communication between documents which do not share the same domain.

Comment: Yes, and so does twitter apparently. There goes that idea. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I don't know about twitter, but if it's the likes count you're trying to get then there are other ways to do so with the graph api.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.connect_widget_button_count_count').text();
```

Divs do not have a value to retrieve.. See http://api.jquery.com/val/

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of  elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.